# How to read and query headers of txt using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a script to read txt file using Pandas.
I need to query on particular type of hearders.
Reading excel is possible but i cannot read txt file.

```
import pandas as pd

#df=pd.read_excel('All.xlsx','Sheet1',dtype={'num1':str},index=False) #works


df=pd.read_csv('read.txt',dtype={'PHONE_NUMBER_1':str}) #doest work

array=['A','C']
a = df['NAME'].isin(array)
b = df[a]
print(b)
```

Comment: ``` File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'BRAND_NAME_1' ```

Comment: It looks like the error is not on the `.read_csv` part when I see the error in the comments with the `KeyError. BRAND_NAME_1`

Comment: Is your file tab delimited or comma separared? It is called `read.txt` which implies tab, but you call `read_csv` which implies comma. It would make sense with your header issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using this syntax.
you are not using the correct key value

```
df=pd.read_csv('read.txt',dtype={'BRAND_NAME_1':str})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table("input.txt", sep=" ", names=('BRAND_NAME_1'), dtype={'BRAND_NAME_1':str})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read file txt then `astype` for column.

Read file:

`pd.read_csv('file.txt', names = ['PHONE_NUMBER_1', 'BRAND_NAME_1'])`

names: is name of columns

Assign type:

```
df['PHONE_NUMBER_1'] = df['PHONE_NUMBER_1'].astype(str)
```